# Reading temperatures from /sys

Tags: java, file-system, io, linux

I have this code which is working fine but I would like to use Java 8 NIO in order to optimize the code performance.

```
public static HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>> getTemp() throws IOException
    {
        HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>> usageData = new HashMap<>();

        File directory = new File("/sys/devices/virtual/thermal");

        File[] fList = directory.listFiles();

        for (File file : fList)
        {
            if (file.isDirectory() && file.getName().startsWith("thermal_zone"))
            {
                File[] listFiles = file.listFiles();
                for (File file1 : listFiles)
                {
                    if (file1.isFile() && file1.getName().startsWith("temp"))
                    {
                        byte[] fileBytes = null;
                        if (file1.exists())
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                fileBytes = Files.readAllBytes(file1.toPath());
                            }
                            catch (AccessDeniedException e)
                            {
                            }

                            if (fileBytes.length > 0)
                            {
                                HashMap<String, Integer> usageData2 = new HashMap<>();

                                String number = file.getName().replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");

                                usageData2.put(number, Integer.parseInt(new String(fileBytes)));

                                usageData.put(number, usageData2);

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return usageData;
    }
```

Can you help me to improve my code?

These are the files that I want to read:

```
/sys/devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp
/sys/devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone1/temp
```

And this is the values into the files:

```
66000
```

Comment: To make life easier for reviewers, please add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about what your code does and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. See also [this meta question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1226/code-should-include-a-description-of-what-the-code-does)

Comment: It just reads some values from files.

Comment: What kind of values? What kind of files? Why? What do you plan on using the values for? Please, give some more context!

Comment: 1) How many files are there? 2) Why do you use those weird nested dictionaries?

Comment: The size of the files is dynamic. On my PC there are two files.

Comment: If there are only two small files, there is little to optimize. If the code is slow it's probably because accessing the sensors themselves is slow and a different IO API should offer little gain. At most you can asynchronously read several sensors at the same time. Optimizing without profiling first is usually a fool's errant. You first need to figure out what's expensive so you can improve that part, instead of wasting time on parts that don't matter.

Answer (score 6):

*"Rewrite my code" is not what code review is about. We review the code you have, and, occasionally, if it helps, we show what we are talking about by writing additional code too. Demands to "Rewrite my code" are not ... polite?*

Still

- Instead of using `File.listFiles` use a [filtered `DirectoryStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newDirectoryStream-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.DirectoryStream.Filter-). Use the filter to discard files that have the wrong name, or are not readable for permission purposes.
- for each file, instead of using the complicated getFIleBytes, you can instead do a grouping reduction in a stream. Consider a method pair:

  ```
  public static String getNumberFromPath(Path path) {
      return path.getFileName().replaceAll("[^\\d]+", "");
  }
  ```

  and a second method:

  ```
  public static int parseUsage(Path path) {
      Files.lines(path).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).first().getAsInt();
  }
  ```

You can then combine those in a `forEach()` on the DirectoryStream above to collect your data. Of course, the double-nesting of the data is odd. Each map in the lower level will have exactly one entry....